# Ubuntu boot failed Error when system is start

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I want to install Ubuntu, and I already have windows 8.1, but when I was installing Ubuntu it asked me for EFI partition when I make a partition 1024mb of EFI then ubuntu installed. Now when i start my system, it shows **"Ubuntu boot failed"** error every time, after pressing Enter it redirects me to grub for choosing OS, when I boot my system with windows and shut down my system it never shut down and go to sleep mode. [Screenshot of disk partition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBhFm.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying. Can you boot Windows from Grub? You say you want to install Ubuntu, but it seems it's already installed. If so is Ubuntu booting from Grub? Is **anything** booting from Grub?

Comment: please answer .